# Can't see nested fields in view when using accepts_nested_attributes_for method while using Ruby 2.3, Rails 5.0, Windows (32-bit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a workout application where you submit a workout that consists of several exercises in rails. I was trying to create a "new" workout view where you can submit a new workout along with nested exercises but my "new" view is only showing the workout form fields, but not the exercise form fields. Btw I'm using Ruby 2.3 and Rails 5.0. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Workout Model (workout.rb)

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :exercises, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises
end
```

Exercise Model (exercise.rb)

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :workout
end
```

Workouts Controller (workouts_controller.rb)

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @workout = Workout.new
        @workout.exercises.build
    end
end
```

New Workout View (views\workouts\new.html.erb)

```
<h1>Create New Workout</h1>

<%= form_for(@workout) do |f| %>
  <%= f.number_field :workout_length, :placeholder => "Workout length   (minutes)" %> <br>
  <%= f.text_field :workout_description, :placeholder => "Workout description" %> <br>

<% f.fields_for :exercises do |builder| %>
<p>
    <%= builder.text_field :exercise_description %>
</p>
<% end %>
  <%= f.submit "SUBMIT WORKOUT" %>
```

Schema (schema.rb)

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161207040053) do
  create_table "exercises", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "exercise_description"
    t.integer  "workout_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
    t.index ["workout_id"], name: "index_exercises_on_workout_id"
  end

  create_table "workouts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "workout_length"
    t.string   "workout_description"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I didn't set up the proper relationship between the exercise and workout model.